# PyQt 5 Checkbox and Button text cut off

Tags: python, pyqt

#### Illustration of Problem

[image: My Problem ( Picture )]

I decided to work with PyQt and immediately encountered a problem and that is the text from my buttons is not displayed correctly and sometimes the buttons are not displayed completely.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

button = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(window)
button.setText("Hello World")
button.show()


window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Add `window.setCentralWidget(button)`, then please read the documentation about [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details) and how [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) work under Qt.

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well for a widget, however I have the same problem when I create a UI with Qt Creator.
On my other computer all buttons are displayed correctly without any additional code, only on my new laptop I have the problem, what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you using layout managers in the UI you created in Designer? Note that at least the top level widget (the "central widget" in Main Windows) **must** have a layout. Read more about [using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)

Comment: thanks, it finally worked